# diablo 2 on Lubuntu

Tags: command-line

I have a diablo 2 disc in my disk drive whenever I try to change the execute permission to anybody it Says Error setting permissions: Read-only file system. Help!

Comment: I've never had to make anything executable in order to install Diablo 2. You're using wine to run it anyway.

Comment: I don't have wine, and when I try to get it it doesn't let me.

Comment: "It" doesn't "let" you? I have no idea what that means. If you edit your question, perhaps it'll be possible to answer. You can't run Diablo 2 without wine or maybe Crossover. But I can confirm that I've been running Diablo 2 on Ubuntu with no issues for maybe a decade. So you shouldn't lose hope. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not change permission of a file on a disc because no data on disk can be changed. you should copy it or make an image on your HDD then change it.

While you wanna play Diablo II on Ubuntu I suggest you to install PlayonLinux then you can install from lots of prepared games and win programs.

### Installing PlayonLinux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

To install PlayonLinux you can take a look at [PlayonLinux Community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayOnLinux)
Or just install it via [Ubuntu software center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/playonlinux)

If you have Ubuntu 16.04  I think you should install it from [Noobslab.com](http://www.noobslab.com/)

First: Add the repository by running this command in terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps`

Then: update package list:

`sudo apt-get update`

Finally: installation:

`sudo apt-get install playonlinux`

This will install several libraries which are needed for wine as well as playonlinux.

At end under game category find Diablo II and click on install, It will be easy and automated.

Comment: OK, it did let me change the permission but since i don't have wine and when i try to get it, it doesn't work, so it wont open. Not even with Archive Manager

Comment: If you install PlayonLinux you can instal Diablo 2 or 3 from its installing list. I think you should try it.

Comment: i have Lubuntu not Ubuntu.

Comment: Do I use a CD ROM option or the file option?

Comment: it's file option

Answer (score 0):

### How-to Install and Getting-Started with PlayOnLinux for Lubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus LTS 32/64bit GNU/Linux Desktop

1. Open a Command Line Console Window
2. Setting Up the playonlinux Apt Repository
   `wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add`
3. Refresh it
   `sudo apt-get update`
4. Installing the PlayOnLinux App on Lubuntu
   `sudo su -c "apt-get install playonlinux"`
5. Launch PlayOnLinux
6. Select "Install" button on the tool-bar, and choose what application you wish to install. PlayOnLinux will guide you through the installation process